# Why are function arguments not getting passed recursively via function.apply()?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to chain ajax calls to web services upon completion. These are heavy calls that save files from `input type=file`.

```
//Here's where I chain the requests (example simplified for readability)
saveData(arg1, 
    saveData, [arg1,
        saveData, [arg1, ....);

//Here's my function definition (example simplified for readability)
function saveData(arg1, callBack, callBackArgs) {
 $.ajax({ //Breakpoint 2. placed here shows all parameters - 
          //arg1, callBack and callBackArgs to be null! What gives?
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController")',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        async: true,
        success: function (result) {
            callBack.apply(callBackArgs); //Breakpoint 1. placed here shows callback 
                                          //and callBackArgs to be set perfectly fine
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

What am I missing? Why is `function.apply()` not working recursively? Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: The `.apply()` method takes 2 arguments: the first is the desired `this` value, and the second is the array of arguments.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please post your comment as an answer so I can close this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.apply()` function takes **two** arguments:

```
  callback.apply(undefined, callBackArgs);
```

That assumes that you don't need `this` to be bound to anything.